# Is there a way to create a blur effect without using backdrop-filter: blur that causes flickering?

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

I'm working on a complex design that involves multiple blur effects, a div that has a blur effect applied, and another div behind it that needs to be blurred. I've been searching online, but I can't find an answer

The current filter **backdrop-filter: blur();** is causing flickering/glitching on non-flagship phones, and I believe nobody truly wants to create a poor user experience through their work.

Has any frontend developer found a solution or encountered such an experience? Any guidance would mean a lot!

Comment: Have you updated the browsers on the non-flagship phones?  I'm using tons of CSS animations together in this app (https://entitycs.github.io/react-burning-ritual/), and had issues testing on (very) old mobile devices, until they surprisingly ceased being issues once I updated the browser.

Comment: You question seems similar to "How can I have high performance graphics on low performance devices?"

Answer (score 1):

Try explicitly forcing GPU rendering via CSS `will-change: filter;`

[Will Change](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/will-change)

If you use a transform, [use it as 3D](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_transforms/Using_CSS_transforms), not as 2D

Answer (score 1):

I am having an issue with the blur effect as well, but one solution I found often is to use: `-webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(5px)` before your `backdrop-filter: blur(5px)`, apparently this fixed most weird interactions between mobile browsers and css.

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>Blur Effect</title>
<style>
  .container {
            position: relative;
            width: 300px;
            height: 200px;
            overflow: hidden;
        }

        .background {
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            background: url('your-background-image.jpg') center/cover;
            filter: blur(10px);
            z-index: -1;
        }

        .content {
            position: relative;
            z-index: 1;
            padding: 20px;
            color: white;
            font-size: 20px;
        }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
<div class="background"></div>
<div class="content">
 <p>Your content goes here.</p>
  </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This works well when it comes to images, but when it comes to some element, I haven't been able to see the effect. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).